# ROS2 : ZED 2i Pointcloud filtering

Tags: ros2, pointcloud

I am trying to filter out white points from the ZED2i published pointcloud and I am encountering a lot of issues.

```
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1707101581
    nanosec: 803938020
  frame_id: zed_left_camera_frame
height: 360
width: 640
fields:
 - name: x
  offset: 0
  datatype: 7
  count: 1
 - name: y
  offset: 4
  datatype: 7
  count: 1
 - name: z
  offset: 8
  datatype: 7
  count: 1
 - name: rgb
  offset: 12
  datatype: 7
  count: 1
is_bigendian: false
point_step: 16
row_step: 10240
data:
 - 255
 - 255
 - 255
 - 127
 - 255
 - 255
 - 255
 - 127
 - 255
 - 255
 - 255
 - 127
 - 255
 - 255
 - 255
 - 127
 - 255
 - 255
 - 255
 - 127
 - 255
 - 255
 - 255
 - 127
 - 255
 - 255
 - 255
 - 127
 - 255
 - 255
 - 255
 - 127
```

This is what I get from the ros2 topic echo that the zed 2i camera publishes,
I created a custom code, where I am trying to create a condition based on the data field so that it omits points with rgb values below 200, by creating a new pointcloud, ‘filtered_points’ that is the exact same as the original, but with only the desired values. However, it is publishing no points or messages on rviz2.

ZED2i - each point of the point cloud is a data composed of 4 32bit floating point values in the format XYZBGRA.

I think I am not converting it correctly

If you have any suggestions to approach this problem it would be greatly appreciated.

Custom Code:

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2
import numpy as np

class pc(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("pc")
        self.pc_org_sub = self.create_subscription(
            PointCloud2, "/zed/zed_node/point_cloud/cloud_registered",
            self.pc_callback, 10)
        self.pc_new_pub = self.create_publisher(
            PointCloud2, "/PointCloud2_filtered", 10)
        self.get_logger().info("Node has been started")

    # Subscriber
    def pc_callback(self, pc: PointCloud2):
        # Assuming RGB fields are at offset 12, 13, 14 and have datatype uint8
        rgb_offset = 12
        rgb_values = np.frombuffer(pc.data, dtype=np.uint8)[rgb_offset::pc.point_step]

        # Check if all RGB values are above 200
        if np.all(rgb_values > 200):
            # Extract all the data
            desirable_data = pc.data

            # Create a new PointCloud2 message with all the data
            filtered_pc = PointCloud2()
            filtered_pc.header = pc.header
            filtered_pc.height = pc.height
            filtered_pc.width = pc.width
            filtered_pc.fields = pc.fields
            filtered_pc.is_bigendian = pc.is_bigendian
            filtered_pc.point_step = pc.point_step
            filtered_pc.row_step = pc.row_step
            filtered_pc.data = desirable_data

            # Publish the new PointCloud2 message
            self.pc_new_pub.publish(filtered_pc)

        else:
            return


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    node = pc()
    rclpy.spin(node)
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please format the code in your question correctly

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced in working with PointClouds, but once I gave a try to the module PointCloud2 from sensors_msgs. You can access to it using the next line `import sensor_msgs.point_cloud2`. There you have some functions like `read_points` and `create_cloud`. I attach the API reference https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/sensor_msgs/html/namespacesensor__msgs_1_1point__cloud2.html#a5d969a10974e5f12199d0da5a7f3ec92. Perhaps you could give it a try and see if it performs better! I don't know if it could be related to ordered pointclouds, if you are removing points from the cloud, you perhaps need to resize the height and width fields?